# angularjs reinitializing arrays gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs

I am running into a peculiar problem.

I have a my view of drop down list as this in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='ConfigurableInputController as configurableInput'>
       <select class="fixed-input"
             ng-model="configurableInput.selectedCriteria"
             ng-change="configurableInput.update()" 
             ng-options="criterion.selected as criterion.name for criterion in configurableInput.criteriaList">
            <option value="">--Please select the comparison criteria--</option>
      </select>
```

The above shows me 3 options in drop down list: Store, Channel and Permissions.
When ever I change the option from Store to Channel or Permissions or any combination the view changes (input boxes, certain labels etc.)

My update() method in controller does this:

```
configurableInput.update = function () {
      configurableInput.permission = "";
      configurableInput.id1 = "";
      configurableInput.id2 = "";
      configurableInput.items1 = "";
      configurableInput.items2 = "";
      configurableInput.defaultValueArray = [];
      configurableInput.permissionsArr = [];
}
```

On selection of the drop down item, I do a ng-click on a button which retrieves information from Db.

There are 2 flavors of methods which are called on ng-click but the one giving me trouble is this one in the Service method:

```
StoreConfigurableService.$inject = ['$q', '$http', 'ApiBasePath'];
function ConfigurableService($q, $http, ApiBasePath) {
  var service = this;
  var defaultValueArr = [];
  var permissionsArr = [];
  var items1 = "";
  var items2 = "";

    service.retrievePermissions = function (criterion, id1, id2, rlNumber1, rlNumber2) {
        $q.all([
            $http.get(ApiBasePath + "/" + criterion + "/" + id1 + "/" + rlNumber1),
            $http.get(ApiBasePath + "/" + criterion + "/" + id2 + "/" + rlNumber2)
        ])
        .then(function (response) {
           items1 = response[0].data;
           items2 = response[1].data;

           if (criterion === 'Permissions') {
               var processed = false;
               permissionsArr = makePermissionsArray(permissionsArr, items1, items2, processed);
           } 
        })
        .catch(function (errorResponse) {
          console.log("Error: " + errorResponse);
          throw errorResponse;
        });
    };
    ... so on
```

In my makePermissionsArray() I am doing this:

```
function makePermissionsArray(arr, items1, items2, processed) {
       var map = items1.storePermissions;
       var map2 = items2.storePermissions;
       var map3 = items1.allPermissions;

       for (var key in map) {
                arr.push({
                    'code': key,
                    'description': map3[key],
                    'repStorePermission1': map[key],
                    'repStorePermission2': map2[key]
                });
       }
}
```

I get this permissionsArr back to controller through this:

```
service.getPermissionsArr = function () {
        return permissionsArr;
};
```

NOTE that 'arr' in the argument of method makePermissionsArray() is not initialized because I am getting it by passing permissionsArr in the argument.

Now how the flow goes is:

1. First I select Store from drop down list, click on button to retrieves configurables for the store. This gives me correct response.
2. Then I select 'Permissions' from drop down list, click on button to retrieve permission configurables from Db, it gets stuck and does not get me any response.

I thought I am not clearing the arrays correctly in update() method and after some long search I found and changed these array initializing from:

```
configurableInput.defaultValueArray = [];
configurableInput.permissionsArr = [];
```

to

```
configurableInput.defaultValueArray.length = 0;
configurableInput.permissionsArr.length = 0;
```

in my update() method.

Now what happens is this:

1. First I select Store from drop down list, click on button to retrieves configurables for the store. This gives me correct response.
2. Then I select 'Permissions' from drop down list, click on button to retrieves permission configurables from Db, it gives me correct response.
3. I select Store from drop down list again, click on button and I get correct response.
4. But when I again select 'Permissions' from drop down list, click on button, it gives me this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Error I get is at this point:

```
arr.push({
     'code': key,
     'description': map3[key],
     'repStorePermission1': map[key],
     'repStorePermission2': map2[key]
});
```

I am literally tearing my hair out because of this problem. Can someone please help me what's wrong?

Comment: Check if `arr` contains an array type in all cases. It may be failing if it is null/undefined/non-array etc. You may need to check the value in chrome debugging mode or log it's value to console to verify.

Comment: Yatin, I added this in my makePermissionsArray() method: if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
                    console.log("Its an array");
                } else {
                    console.log("It is not an array");
                }

Comment: 1st time it gives me - Its an array. 2nd time it gives me - It is not an array. Any idea what could be going wrong the 2nd time?

Comment: I am trying to understand why it may be setting it to not an array.

Comment: I think the initalizers for setting `array = []` are better. Bring them in. I am still analysing your code.

Comment: you are using 
permissionsArr = makePermissionsArray(...), 
but you dont seem to return arr from makePermissionsArray

Comment: I think this makes permissiosArr not an array second time

Comment: Nikhil! That solves my issue. I don't believe I was missing something so basic. Thank you guys for looking into this issue for me. Big love to you both!